# Rails 5 link_to specific controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have following routing problem in Rails 5:

```
<%= link_to product.id, product %>
```

generates a link like this

> localhost:3000/products/12345

What I want is a link to the "ext" action in the products controller:

> localhost:3000/products/ext/12345

If I try to build a link like this

```
 <%= link_to 'To the product', :controller => :products, :action => :ext %>
```

it gives back following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"ext", :controller=>"products"}

In the routes.rb I have

```
  get "products/ext/:id", to: "products#ext"
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your routes to

```
get "products/ext/:id", to: "products#ext", as: :products_ext
```

and change your view to

```
<%= link_to products_ext_path(product) %>
```